# Deluge Web and init.d Issues

Tags: vpn, init.d, deluge

I'm having trouble getting Deluge Web to work. I'm a bit of a noob, so bare with me.

My Pi is set to automatically connect to my VPN provider and run Deluge on boot. The problem is, I want to have the Deluge Web interface. When I try to install the Web UI, I get these errors.

```
Setting up deluged (1.3.10-3+deb8u1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'vpn.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service minidlna and vpn.sh if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service vpn.sh at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service minidlna at depth 1
insserv: Stopping vpn.sh depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package deluged (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 deluged
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The init.d scripts look okay to me, but like I said I'm new. Here's vpn.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo openvpn --client --config /mnt/torrents/openvpn/[VPN].ovpn --ca /mnt/torrents/openvpn/[VPN].crt --script-security 2
```

And here's minidlna:

```
# Function that signals log rotation to the daemon/service
#
do_rotate()
{
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --signal USR1 --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC " "$NAME"
    do_start
    case "$?" in
                0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
  ;;
  stop)
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
                0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
  status)
       status_of_proc -p "$PIDFILE" "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
       ;;
  restart|force-reload)
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
          0|1)
                if [ "$1" = "force-reload" ]; then
                        # Rescan the collection
                        DAEMON_ARGS="$DAEMON_ARGS -R"
                fi
                do_start
                case "$?" in
                        0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
                        1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
                        *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
                esac
                ;;
          *)
                # Failed to stop
                log_end_msg 1
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
  rotate)
        log_daemon_msg "Reopening log file $LOGFILE"
        do_rotate
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload|rotate}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac

:
```

Any help would be appreciated.